# Amazon S3 Multi-Image Upload with PHP and Javascript

Tags: javascript, php, amazon-s3

Alright.... so after searching for days I am officially stuck. My problem seems pretty simple but every time I think I am on the right track I get stopped.

I have a simple html form that has the option for the user to upload a few pictures. I need to store these using Amazon S3 which doesn't support multi-file upload with POST. Is there ANY way I can workaround this limitation? Maybe a PHP script to upload them sequentially?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: did you ever get this worked out?

Answer (score 1):

I just had a look at the SDK. One of the sample php files shows multiple file uploads (_samples/cli-s3_get_urls_for_uploads.php).

You'll have to;

- have the user upload their files and **store** them on your website (temp)
- add files to a batch send `$s3->batch()->create_object();`
- then send them off with `$s3->batch()->send();`

Comment: hi Savid, I'm trying to do multi-file upload to S3 using PHP right now but am still somewhat of a novice. Would you mind sharing more of your code in your answer?

Comment: `batch()` gives me this error `Call to undefined method S3::batch()`